# Undefined variable for input argument in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
    function [B1] = n10278273RotatingRod([x0,y0]; t)
%RotationRod function accepts a vector with initial position x1, y1 and rotates
%for time (t). Giving the final position as an output.
B0 = [x0, y0] %initial location of first rod
R = rotx(sin(2*t/pi)) %constructs a matrix to rotate the input vector (A)
B1 = B0*R
end
```

Trying to rotate a vector, getting the following error:
"Undefined function or variable 'x0'."

Comment: Your error refers to an execution error. This is a function. In what context is it executed ? Anyway, your function statement isn't correct,  `function [B1] = n10278273RotatingRod(x0,y0, t)` is the right way to do it.

Comment: I've corrected this but get the same error

Comment: Well as said, you lack the context of execution : provide a small , simple piece of code where your function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a syntax error. You should define your function as:
function [B1] = n10278273RotatingRod(x0,y0,t)

Comment: as @PTRK mentioned, you should provide a small piece of code where your function is executed with a small data sample. Question: what happen when you run (=execute) your function like this: n10278273RotatingRod(1, 2, 3) ?